# Qt how to get the word that was clicked on in a table or list view (widget)?

Tags: qt

I need to get the word that was clicked on in a table widget or table view cell (or a list widget (view)).

The table (list) view or widget is not editable.

Is it possible? If so, how would I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complicated task.

Firstly, attach an event filter to the view's `viewport()` and monitor mouse events. `QMouseEvent` object will contain viewport coordinates. Use `QAbstractItemView::indexAt` to find out which model index was clicked. Use `QAbstractItemView::visualRect` to obtain the index's rectangle. `event->pos() - visual_rect.topLeft()` will give you mouse coordinates relative to the view item.

Here comes the most complicated part. There is no way to determine positions of words. Default Qt delegate doesn't have any API for that. And the docs don't have any information about how exactly the text is drawn. Item appearance can be changed because of stylesheets, model data or even operation system.

So we need to create our own gelegate to have full control of drawing. Create a subclass of `QStyledItemDelegate` and reimplement `sizeHint` and `paint`. In `sizeHint` determine total size of text using `QFontMetrics::boundingRect`. In `paint` do the painting as you want.

Now we know exactly how the text is drawn. We know the font, the initial position, etc. The last step is to determine the bounding rect of each word. Let our example text be `"word1 word2 word3"`. Use `QFontMetrics::boundingRect` to determine bounding rects of the texts `"word1"`, `"word1 word2"`, `"word1 word2 word3"`. Subtract the first rectangle from the second to obtain the bounding rect of `"word2"`. Subtract the second rectangle from the third to obtain the bounding rect of `"word3"`. Apply padding to these rectangles if you used padding while drawing text.

Now you know the click position in the item coordinates and the words' bounding rects. It's all you need.

Comment: Wow! That IS complicated. Thanks, Pavel.